# replace image button with text link

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to know if there is a way to replace the image button in the code below with a text link through css. This is a crm where the html page is not open for edit. Only the style sheet can be edited. The image could be replaced, but it would be a file with the same name.

```
<table class="MoreButTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a onmouseout="AndarButtonMouseOut('MoreButton');window.status='';return true;" onmouseover="AndarButtonMouseOver('MoreButton','../Style/SubtleButtons/AgencySearchOver.gif');window.status='&lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;';return true;" href="javascript:WasItClicked=true; document.forms['Designation'].NavigationButton.value='More';document.forms['Designation'].submit();">
                    <img title="&lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;" alt="&lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;" name="MoreButton" src="../Style/SubtleButtons/AgencySearch.gif">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your css code?

Comment: Please update your question to include the current CSS realevant to your HTML extract.

Comment: I would suggest that the current CSS he has for the HTML supplied is irrelevant to the question in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can target the link specifically with CSS, then yes you can.

Hide the image and use a pseudo-**element** on the link.

```css
a [name="MoreButton"] {
  display: none;
}
a::before {
  content: 'You can seem me but not the image';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">
  <img title="Title" alt="ALt Text" name="MoreButton" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D that worked. I had to target the specific link like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, use a pseudo selector:

```css
a img {
  display: none;
}
a:before {
  content: 'Click me';
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</a>
```